# Azure Web App for Containers - Not enough disk space to start the Web App's container

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have an App Service Plan on Azure with 2 Web Apps created from Windows based Docker images.
For each app I have one additional staging slot.

From today I'm not able to start one of the staging apps, I get following error:

> Unable to start container. Error message: Not enough disk space to start container. Current available space: 1566 MB. New container estimated disk space: 1707 MB

When I check File system storage for App Service Plan, it says that I'm using only 20MB out of 250GB.

Is it possible that Azure is storing old images locally?
How to free some space?

Comment: what is the plan you chose?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm using PC2 pricing plan

Comment: No, it's not available when using containers. But PC2 is better plan than B2.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I was able to make this work by scaling to larger plan, restarting containers and scaling it back down. After that I was able to restart containers multiple times without scaling it up again.

Answer (score 0):

What Windows base image are you using? You have mentioned that you’re unable to start one of the staging apps, does it happen with prod/swap as well?  Windows Containers are deployed onto the *local SSD Storage in each instance* within the App Service Plan.

The first time you use a custom Docker image, we will do a "docker pull" and pull all layers. These layers are stored on disk just as if you were using Docker on-premises. When we do a "docker pull" after a site restart, we will only pull layers that have changed. If there have been no changes, we will simply use existing layers on the local disk. More details [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-windows-containers/wiki/things-you-should-know#available-resources-per-app-service-plan-sku).

Yes, checkout the maximum available storage/App Service Plan SKU:

PC2/19 GB | PC3/60 GB | PC4/79 GB

Review the dockerfile config for the EntryPoint of the container. All apps in the same App Service Plan share the same resources, you need to review each app.

To isolate the issue, generally you may try and run the image locally or swap/production . You're free to use a different custom Docker image to run your app. However, you must choose the right parent image for the framework you want. It takes some time to download a parent image during app start-up. However, you can reduce start-up time by using one of the following parent images that are already cached in Azure App Service:

- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
- mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 - this image is the base
  container used across Microsoft ASP.NET Core Microsoft Windows Nano
  Server images.

Kindly let us know how it goes for further investigation.